# Custom padding for convolutions in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, caffe

In tensorflow function [tf.nn.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d), the padding option just has 'SAME' and 'VALID'.

But in the conv layer of Caffe, there is [pad option](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html) can define the number of pixels to (implicitly) add to each side of the input.

How to achieve that in Tensorflow?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `tf.pad()` (see the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad)) to pad the Tensor before applying `tf.nn.conv2d(..., padding="VALID")` (valid padding means no padding).

---

For instance, if you want to pad the image with 2 pixels in height, and 1 pixel in width, and then apply a convolution with a 5x5 kernel:

```py
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 3])
padded_input = tf.pad(input, [[0, 0], [2, 2], [1, 1], [0, 0]], "CONSTANT")

filter = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [5, 5, 3, 16])
output = tf.nn.conv2d(padded_input, filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID")
```

`output` will have shape `[None, 28, 26, 16]`, because you have only a padding of 1 in width.