# Custom padding (Float Type) for transpose convolutions in TensorFlow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning, padding

I'm working on a TensorFlow transpose convolution model where (batch size, layer height, layer width, output channel) is (100, 25, 25, 64).
Now I'm applying a transpose operation where the kernel of size 4 x 4 with a stride is 2 and padding is 0.25. My aim is to get output size 50 e.g. (100, 50, 50, 64)
I checked [Stack OverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659538/custom-padding-for-convolutions-in-tensorflow) and [tfpad](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad) where pad type mentioned Init32. 
It will be a great help if any of you kindly suggest how can I use padding of type float or how can I get size output layer size 50 after transpose operation.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with a padding of 0.25? One usually thinks of whole amounts of padding.

Comment: Yes, as per the updated articles there is no concept of implementing floating points as padding. Hence, the padding is done as a whole amount (i.e., 1, 2). I am working on a model where there is a requirement of 0.25 in all sides to maintain the expected shape of output layer. Now, I have modified the formula of calculating output size (for this special case) and fortunately its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding carries only zero. So it doesn't matter if it is float or anything else.